# Retrieved Data from Database looks shows as "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@152ed1d9" instead of text Android 2.2.3

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've only been coding for a couple of weeks and have no prior experience so please forgive stupid questions and terrible code!

The Goal:
On the click of a button randomly pull some data from a Database and display it in a TextView.

The Challenge:
It seems to pull the data from the database however what is displayed is the following "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@XXXXXXXX" where "XXXXXXXX" is made up of numbers and letters (looks like Hexidecimal)

Here's the code for MainActivity:

```
package com.example.mat.databaseclick1;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Button generate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Generate);
    generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DBHelper myDatabaseHelper = new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);
            myDatabaseHelper.open();
            String text = String.valueOf(myDatabaseHelper.getRProgram());
            myDatabaseHelper.close();
            TextView result2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result2);
            result2.setText(text);
        }
    });

    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);
    //---add a program---
        db.open();
    long id = db.insertProgram("Program One");
    id = db.insertProgram("Program Two");
    id = db.insertProgram("Program Three");
    id = db.insertProgram("Program Four");
    db.close();
    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getRProgram();
    if (c.moveToFirst())
        DisplayProgram(c);
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "No program found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    db.close();
}
public void DisplayProgram(Cursor c)
{
    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    result.setText("id:" + c.getString(0) + "\n" + "Program:" + c.getString(1));
}
}
```

And heres the Database Adaptor:

```
package com.example.mat.databaseclick1;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static android.R.attr.data;

public class DBHelper {
static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
static final String KEY_NAME = "program";
static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";
static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "programs";
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table programs (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "program text not null);";
final Context context;
DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBHelper(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS programs");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}


//---opens the database---
public DBHelper open() throws SQLException {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//---closes the database---
public void close() {
    DBHelper.close();
}

//---insert a program into the database---
public long insertProgram(String program) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, program);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

//---deletes a particular program---
public boolean deleteProgram(long rowId) {
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

//---retrieves all the programs---
public Cursor getAllPrograms() {
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

//---retrieves a particular program---
public Cursor getProgram(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID,
                            KEY_NAME},
                    KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

//---updates a program---
public boolean updateProgram(long rowId, String program) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_NAME, program);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

//---retrieves random program---
public Cursor getRProgram() {
    Cursor mCursor= db.query(DATABASE_TABLE,null,null,null,null,null,"RANDOM()");
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}

//----retrieves random program by click-----

    public String[] clicktogetprog() {

        final String DATABASE_TABLE = "programs";

        String rprogresult;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE;
        SQLiteDatabase db  = this.DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor      = db.query(selectQuery,null,null,null,null,null,"RANDOM()");
        String data      = ("id:" + cursor.getString(0) + "\n" + "Program:" + cursor.getString(1));

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                // get the data into array, or class variable
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return new String[]{String.valueOf(data)};
    }
}
```

Any help would be most appreciated!

Thanks in advance
:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok just figured it out and its all working. Seems the result I was getting back was something to do with the Cursors position.

To correct it I opened the Database and then moved the cursor ("d" to a random position in the database. I then got it to call "DisplayProgram". In displayprogram I put in the TextView "result2" and then set the text in "result2" by specifying the id with d.getString(0) adn the program with d.getString(1). Here's the working code for MainActivity (I didnt have to change the Database Adapter).
Hope it helps someone else out:

MainActivity 
    package com.example.mat.databaseclick1;

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Button generate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Generate);
    generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DBHelper myDatabaseHelper = new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);
            myDatabaseHelper.open();
            Cursor d = myDatabaseHelper.getRProgram();
            if (d.moveToFirst());
            DisplayProgram(d);
            myDatabaseHelper.close();

        }
        public void DisplayProgram (Cursor d){
            TextView result2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result2);
            result2.setText("id:" + d.getString(0) + "\n" + "Program:" + d.getString(1));
        }
    });


    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);
    //---add a program---
        db.open();
long id = db.insertProgram("Program One");
id = db.insertProgram("Program Two");
id = db.insertProgram("Program Three");
id = db.insertProgram("Program Four");
    db.close();
    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getRProgram();
    if (c.moveToFirst())
        DisplayProgram(c);
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "No program found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    db.close();
}



public void DisplayProgram(Cursor c)
{
    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    result.setText("id:" + c.getString(0) + "\n" + "Program:" + c.getString(1));
}
```

}

Comment: When you create a cursor, the cusror is positioned **before the first row** (position **-1**). This allows `while (csr.moveToNext) ...` to traverse all rows. You can also do `csr.moveToPosition(-1)`. Position 0 is the first row.

Comment: ah ok - didnt know that, Thanks Mike